# Trying to create a connect metamask feature

Tags: javascript, html, metamask

I cannot for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong.
I am following the metamask docs and everything: https://docs.metamask.io/guide/create-dapp.html#basic-action-part-1

.html button:

```
 <!DOCTYPE hmtl>
<html lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" >
    
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdlivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js"></script>

    <script src="./javafilename.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block mb-3" id="connectButton" value="Connect" enabled></button>
<body>
</html>
```

metamask java:

```
const initialize = () => {
    //Basic Actions Section
    const onboardButton = document.getElementById('connectButton');
  };
```

Comment: Any error? a code sandbox will help

Comment: What's the problem? All necessary information should be included in the post. Please read "[ask]".

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an error in your code, it just that you need to keep following the instructions, by giving the current code i can see its working, take a look at this Codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-frost-f4zgd7?file=/index.html

If you notice, when you click the button, it tell us Metamask is installed

Few points.

- On the documentation, they load this when the window load `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initialize);` and you want to do it on a button, see `onclick="initialize()"`

Also please make sure for other questions to provide an error or something so the community can help you better

Comment: Tysm dude, sorry, I'm new to all of this. Will do next time!

Comment: Np Fraser, we are here to help!